# Not able to Install Mongo Db on AWS Linux 2023

Tags: mongodb, openssl, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install mongodb in Amazon Linux with below configuration

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2023"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="2023"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:al2023"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2023"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2023"
HOME_URL="https://aws.amazon.com/linux/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023"
SUPPORT_END="2028-03-01"
```

I tried to install using Tarball and repo. However it got failed with below error

```
[root@ip ~]# mongod --version

mongod: /lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by mongod)

mongod: /lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by mongod)

mongod: /lib64/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by mongod)

[root@ip ~]# openssl version

OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023)

[root@i ~]#
```

```
tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-amazon2-6.0.5.tgz
mongod version
```

Comment: AWS have removed 1500 RPMs from AL2023 compared to what was in AL2.  They've also standardised on openssl 3 which makes dragging in other RPMs more problematic.   Of course AWS would prefer you to use their mongo service and their IPSEC service and their DNS service....

Answer (score 7):

I got this working in AWS Linux 2023 (aka AL2023) by

edit  `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-7.0.repo` with the content:

```
[mongodb-org-AL2023]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2023/mongodb-org/development/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-7.0.asc
```

Then install packages with `yum install mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-database-tools-extra`

You'll get a key prompt like this

```
Importing GPG key 0x1785BA38:
 Userid     : "MongoDB 7.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>"
 Fingerprint: E588 3020 1F7D D82C D808 AA84 160D 26BB 1785 BA38
 From       : https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-7.0.asc
Is this ok [y/N]: y
```

After that you'll have a new systemd service called `mongod.service` to treat as normal.

---

Now, some caveats:

- This hasn't been announced yet AFAIK so perhaps don't run production loads straight off, or at least have backups/snapshots.
- Look in https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2023/mongodb-org/development/x86_64/RPMS/  and there are RPMs that won't install by name because of dependencies.  Be aware.

Good luck !

Comment: Mongo 7.0 appears to be available now. Earlier releases 
 are listed but don't have the mongodb-org rpms. https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2023/mongodb-org/7.0/x86_64/RPMS/